# Running Eclipse WindowTester Pro test from ant script

Tags: ant, eclipse-rcp, window-tester

I am using this script to launch WTP test

```
<ant target="ui-test" antfile="${eclipse-test-library-file}" dir="${eclipse-test-home}">
    <property name="product" value="${productName}" />
    <property name="application" value="${applicationName}" />
    <property name="os" value="${baseos}"/>
    <property name="ws" value="${basews}"/>
    <property name="arch" value="${basearch}"/>
    <property name="data-dir" value="${eclipse-test-home}/junit-workspace -clean" />
    <property name="plugin-name" value="${pluginName}" />
    <property name="classname" value="${testClassName}" />
</ant>
```

The workbench launched but the test did not run. Am I missing something in the ant property?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to judge what's missing in your setup, but there is an example project for running WindowTester tests from an Ant script here:
http://code.google.com/p/windowtester/downloads/detail?name=WindowTester_AntExample_v1.0.zip

If the example works for you, it should be easy to compare it to your project and find out the difference.